# How to Fill a DataSet by using multiple delimited text files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I work on C# .My input file look likes :

```
d00 d04 WinMain
d00 d04    lpCmdLine: '/UNREGSERVER'
d00 d04 Run
d00 d04 
           lpCmdLine: '/UNREGSERVER'
d00 d04    nCmdShow: 10
d00 d04 leaving WinMain   

CustomerID  CompanyName ContactName ContactTitle    Address City    Region  PostalCode  Country Phone   Fax
ALFKI   Alfreds Futterkiste Maria Anders    Sales Representative    Obere Str. 57   Berlin  NULL    12209   Germany 030-0074321 030-0076545
ANATR   Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados  Ana Trujillo    Owner   Avda. de la Constitución 2222   México D.F. NULL    05021   Mexico  (5) 555-4729    (5) 555-3745
ANTON   Antonio Moreno Taquería Antonio Moreno  Owner   Mataderos  2312 México D.F. NULL    05023   Mexico  (5) 555-3932    NULL
AROUT   Around the Horn Thomas Hardy    Sales Representative    120 Hanover Sq. London  NULL    WA1 1DP UK  (171) 555-7788  (171) 555-6750
BERGS   Berglunds snabbköp  Christina Berglund  Order Administrator Berguvsvägen  8 Luleå   NULL    S-958 22    Sweden  0921-12 34 65   0921-12 34 67
BLAUS   Blauer See Delikatessen Hanna Moos  Sales Representative    Forsterstr. 57  Mannheim    NULL    68306   Germany 0621-08460  0621-08924
BLONP   Blondesddsl père et fils    Frédérique Citeaux  Marketing Manager   24, place Kléber    Strasbourg  NULL    67000   France  88.60.15.31 88.60.15.32
BOLID   Bólido Comidas preparadas   Martín Sommer   Owner   C/ Araquil, 67  Madrid  NULL    28023   Spain   (91) 555 22 82  (91) 555 91 99
BONAP   Bon app'    Laurence Lebihan    Owner   12, rue des Bouche
```

---

```
d00 d04 WinMain
d00 d04    lpCmdLine: '/UNREGSERVER'
d00 d04 Run
d00 d04 
           lpCmdLine: '/UNREGSERVER'
d00 d04    nCmdShow: 10
d00 d04 leaving WinMain  

CustomerID  CompanyName ContactName ContactTitle    Address City    Region  PostalCode  Country Phone   Fax
ALFKI   Alfreds Futterkiste Maria Anders    Sales Representative    Obere Str. 57   Berlin  NULL    12209   Germany 030-0074321 030-0076545
ANATR   Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados  Ana Trujillo    Owner   Avda. de la Constitución 2222   México D.F. NULL    05021   Mexico  (5) 555-4729    (5) 555-3745
ANTON   Antonio Moreno Taquería Antonio Moreno  Owner   Mataderos  2312 México D.F. NULL    05023   Mexico  (5) 555-3932    NULL
AROUT   Around the Horn Thomas Hardy    Sales Representative    120 Hanover Sq. London  NULL    WA1 1DP UK  (171) 555-7788  (171) 555-6750
BERGS   Berglunds snabbköp  Christina Berglund  Order Administrator Berguvsvägen  8 Luleå   NULL    S-958 22    Sweden  0921-12 34 65   0921-12 34 67
BLAUS   Blauer See Delikatessen Hanna Moos  Sales Representative    Forsterstr. 57  Mannheim    NULL    68306   Germany 0621-08460  0621-08924
BLONP   Blondesddsl père et fils    Frédérique Citeaux  Marketing Manager   24, place Kléber    Strasbourg  NULL    67000   France  88.60.15.31 88.60.15.32
BOLID   Bólido Comidas preparadas   Martín Sommer   Owner   C/ Araquil, 67  Madrid  NULL    28023   Spain   (91) 555 22 82  (91) 555 91 99
BONAP   Bon app'    Laurence Lebihan    Owner   12, rue des Bouche
```

I want to save this **text files** to **dataset.**How to do that.I write the bellow code to doing this.

```
DataSet ds = TextToDataSet.Convert(@"C:\readme.txt", "MyNewTable", "\t");


public static DataSet Convert(string File,
 string TableName, string delimiter)
{
    //The DataSet to Return

    DataSet result = new DataSet();

    //Open the file in a stream reader.

    StreamReader s = new StreamReader(File);

    //Split the first line into the columns       

    string[] columns = s.ReadLine().Split(delimiter.ToCharArray());

    //Add the new DataTable to the RecordSet

    result.Tables.Add(TableName);

    //Cycle the colums, adding those that don't exist yet 

    //and sequencing the one that do.

    foreach (string col in columns)
    {
        bool added = false;
        string next = "";
        int i = 0;
        while (!added)
        {
            //Build the column name and remove any unwanted characters.

            string columnname = col + next;
            columnname = columnname.Replace("#", "");
            columnname = columnname.Replace("'", "");
            columnname = columnname.Replace("&", "");

            //See if the column already exists

            if (!result.Tables[TableName].Columns.Contains(columnname))
            {
                //if it doesn't then we add it here and mark it as added

                result.Tables[TableName].Columns.Add(columnname);
                added = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //if it did exist then we increment the sequencer and try again.

                i++;
                next = "_" + i.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    //Read the rest of the data in the file.        

    string AllData = s.ReadToEnd();

    //Split off each row at the Carriage Return/Line Feed

    //Default line ending in most windows exports.  

    //You may have to edit this to match your particular file.

    //This will work for Excel, Access, etc. default exports.

    string[] rows = AllData.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray());

    //Now add each row to the DataSet        

    foreach (string r in rows)
    {
        //Split the row at the delimiter.

        string[] items = r.Split(delimiter.ToCharArray());

        //Add the item

        result.Tables[TableName].Rows.Add(items);
    }

    //Return the imported data.        

    return result;
}
```

If i use the multi delimited than error shows.How to use the multi delimited.If i run the code to to load the text file given in above show the bellow error

**Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your delimiter is included in the fields you are delimiting....

In other words, your code would of be fine if instead of spaces, customer name and such, had underscores instead of spaces, that way the split function would only return the columns data.
For example:

```
ALFKI   Alfreds Futterkiste Maria Anders    Sales Representative    Obere Str. 57   Berlin  NULL    12209   Germany 030-0074321 030-0076545
```

Would split as:

```
ALKFI, Alfreds, Futterkiste, Maria, Anders, Sales, Representative.....
```

As you are using space to delimit the fields.

Hope that answers your question :)

EDIT: As stated in one of the comments below i came up with the idea of using RegEx, so here it is:

This will provide you with data for each Line:

```
Match Telephone = Regex.Match(Target, @"\d*-\d*");
Match Fax = Telephone.NextMatch();
Match Country = Regex.Match(Target, @"\w*(?=\s\d{0,3}-)");
Match PCode = Regex.Match(target, @"(?=\s*)\d*(?=\s*" + Country.Value + ")");
```

*Target is the line you read from the file*

I am learning RegEx right now so give me some time for more RegEx expressions...

Comment: plz explain in detail .show some syntax or modify my code .thanks to reply

Comment: You will have to modify your source file, manually spearating the fields with something else than space, so you can split them correctly :p

Comment: I think i can fix that for you so you dont have to. And ill practice RegEx while im at it :D